# What does a red warning icon on a HDD in Windows 7 mean?

Tags: windows-7

First time today I'm seeing this:

[image]

Scans revealed no bad sectors. No bad files are found. No malware was found. No virus was found. I'm at loss what this means.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have a Subversion repository checked out at the root of the drive?

Comment: Is there some sort of backup software service/software being used? And what Antivirus are you using?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the icons used by the [Mozy Backup Software](http://mozy.com/) when you have a drive or folder that has not yet been backed up by the software.  Hence, if you are using Mozy, it's flagging the drive as not (yet) backed up.